# Firebase orderByChild().equalTo() returns the Objekt too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello i'm trying to get data for google-map Markers from my Firebase. I tried it with the `equalTo` Method but it seems to work wrong. I do get the data which i want, but i get it exactly as often as many childs have the property i'm asking for. So for example if i'm asking for the prop city = London, i get an Object with all childs with the city London, but i get this objekt as often as there are childs with this city(like 10 or 20 times) this is not very effective (what if i have someday thousands of props with this city ?)

```
componentWillUpdate (){
   const previousMarker = this.state.markers;

   this.Ref.orderByChild('address').equalTo(this.props.city)

      .on('child_added', snap => {
      previousMarker.push({
          lat: snap.node_.children_.root_.right.left.value.children_.root_.left.value.value_,
          lng: snap.node_.children_.root_.right.left.value.children_.root_.value.value_,
          price: snap.node_.children_.root_.value.value_,
          key: snap.key + "_Marker",

        })
        console.log(previousMarker)

      })
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, the `child_added` event will be called for every child that matches your query, see the documentation for [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events).

If you want a single event to return the entire list of data instead, you should use the `value` event listener. From the [listen for value events documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

> Attaching a `value` observer to a list of data will return the entire
>   list of data as a single snapshot which you can then loop over to
>   access individual children.
>
> ```
>  ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
>      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>          var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
>          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>          // ...
>       });
> });
> ```

You can also use `on('value', ...)` as you would for a child event.